# PHP: Storing data for another instance of your script

Tags: php, session-variables, apc

I was looking for a way to store some data that's coming in through an API and be able to access that data from another instance of the same script. Basically when I get a request I want to hold the data for 5 seconds and see if another request comes in with one of the fields matching within 5 seconds. I've tried this a couple of ways with sessions and using APC. Below is the APC version of the code, the sessions version is the same with the APC bits switched out for corresponding session bits.

What happens is that the second instance of the script does not see the stored information no matter which mechanism I have tried for storing the data.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
//data exists, this is the second request with matching data.
if(apc_exists('key')){
    //do work
    //delete first request data from storage so it does not get processed below.
    apc_delete('key');
} else {
    //no data for this key, store data and wait 5 secs.
    apc_add('key', $data);
    sleep(5);
//stored data still exists, this is the only request coming with this data.
if(apc_exists('key')){
        //do work
    } else {
        //data no longer exists, taken care of by other instance, just exit.
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `'`. Was that a typo here or in your code? `apc_delete('key);`

Comment: Yes, was a typo on here. Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Session mechanism would work only if you were requesting with same browser, so this is not what you are looking for. APC solution however should do the work just fine. Do you have php running as cgi / fcgid ?

Comment: `sleep(5)` in your script means the client browser will not be able to complete the request for at least five seconds. Is that intentional?

Comment: cgi-fcgi according to php_sapi_name(). Would that cause a problem?

Comment: It may, with CGI it will not work, with FCGI it depends on webserver implementation (like mod_fcgid for apache will not work and mmod_fastcgi will). You may better look into redis, memcached and other key-value storage engines, independent form php.

Comment: Switched up to memcached and that did the trick. Thanks for all your suggestions everyone. Especially dev-null-dweller with the solution. It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: @pita please create an answer and mark it.

Comment: Use database to store your information and pass encrypted identifier of each saved information to your request. And pass that identifier in subsequent request to access data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APC is not guaranteed to work with CGI/FastCGI SAPI - you may better look into redis, memcached or other key-value storage engines, independent from php.